# Result of Iterator::max does not live long enough although the item is returned directly

Tags: rust, lifetime

This code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=08f99d1231c549f9676624bc10c9e687&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
let max = {
    let mut v = vec![3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6];
    v.iter().max().unwrap()
};
println!("{}", max);
```

... leads to this error:

```
<anon>:4:9: 4:10 error: `v` does not live long enough
<anon>:4         v.iter().max().unwrap()
                 ^
<anon>:5:7: 7:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 5:6...
<anon>:5     };
<anon>:6     println!("{}", max);
<anon>:7 }
<anon>:3:50: 5:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 3:49
<anon>:3         let mut v = vec![3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6];
<anon>:4         v.iter().max().unwrap()
<anon>:5     };
```

I don't understand this error: [`Iterator::max`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max) returns `Option<Self::Item>`, and not `Option<&Self::Item>`, so max shouldn't be a reference and hence everything should be fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`Vec::iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) which returns an iterator that iterates over the *references* to the vector's elements. The associated type of that iterator is already a reference (`Self::Item = &usize`) There are a few solution to your problem:

- **Dereference the result**

  ```
  *v.iter().max().unwrap()
  ```

  This works fine here, because the elements of `v` are `Copy` types. It does not work for non-`Copy` types!

  ⇒ *good in your case*
- **Clone the result**

  ```
  v.iter().max().unwrap().clone()
  v.iter().max().cloned().unwrap()
  ```

  This works for types that implement `Clone`. Any type that implements `Copy` will also implement `Clone`, but not all types that implement `Clone` will implement `Copy`.

  ⇒ *good in the general case of using `max`/`min`*
- **Use [`Iterator::cloned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned)**

  ```
  v.iter().cloned().max().unwrap()
  ```

  Efficiency-wise, this is only acceptable for `Copy` types, as it clones every element in the iterator. This will be expensive if cloning isn't cheap.

  ⇒ *bad for using `min`/`max` in general, but handy in other situations*
- **Use `Vec::into_iter`**

  ```
  v.into_iter().max().unwrap()
  ```

  The problem with this method is that you can't use `v` afterwards.

  ⇒ *bad for using `min`/`max` in general, but handy in other situations*

Comment: Could you please explain why you consider the latter two options "bad in this case"? I would personally have written this with `cloned()` or `into_iter()`, for instance.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thanks, that was indeed a confusing formulation. I didn't mean to talk about "*this*" case, but rather about the general case. Of course in my example code it would not make a difference to use the latter two options. But in the general case of having a vector and wanting to find the min/max, `into_iter` and `cloned` are probably not what you want.